# Swift constants which one is better?

Tags: swift, struct, constants

I have two separate arguments for handling constants in swift. The single structure handles all the constants in the application. Here is a small snippet of the code and I need suggestions on which format is better.

Format A:

```
struct VIConstants{

    static let XEPORT_AUTHORIZE_URL = isStaging ? "xyyyy" : "xyxyx"
    static let XEPORT_TOKEN_URL = isStaging ? "tokenUrl" : "prodTokenUrl"
    static let XEPORT_CLIENT_ID = "xyz" 
    static let XEPORT_CLIENT_SECRET = "yyye"
    static let XEPORT_REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:3200/callback"
    static let XEPORT_SCOPES = "scopes"
}
```

Format B:

```
struct VIConstants{

    struct Authentication{
        static let clientId = "xxxxx"
        static let clientSecret = "xxxx"
        static let scopes = "xxxxx"

        static let authUrl = isStaging ? "xxx" : "xyxyxy"
        static let tokenUrl = "sampleURL"
        static let redirectUri = "sampleredirect"
    }
}
```

Note that there are more structures inside `VIConstants` that are for different other constants throughout the app. 
What I am looking for is suggestion on which one to choose

Comment: This is off-topic as it would be down to each persons preference/opinion. I prefer the bottom one myself as it groups/namespaces them better but other people would have other arguments/opinions. This question will likely be closed via the review queue as 'primarily opinion based'

Comment: @Scriptable the question itself is about opinion. I am not trying to put up arguments. Just an opinion would be helpful

Comment: I am not suggesting anything about arguments etc. It's just that questions that are opinionated are off-topic, so it will very likely be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Swift API guideline, Names of types and protocols are UpperCamelCase. Everything else is lowerCamelCase.

https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

Following their conventions, Format B is preferred.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking more about the structural differences than the naming conventions.